# Associate Silverlight Unit Tests with Test Cases

Tags: msbuild, silverlight-4.0, automated-tests

I just added a Silverlight Unit Test Application (project) to my Solution to test my SL4 App.
Also added a Silverlight Test Class to that same project and created a simple test.

I'm using SL4, VS2010 and TFS2010 automated builds.

I'm not being able to associate that test to one of my test cases. Any reasons why?

Though, the associated automation test window detects unit tests belonging to a standard SL4 Test Project (included in the same solution).

Thank you,
Nuno Senica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the follow - [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/04/02/unit-testing-with-silverlight.aspx) 
Seems it should help you..

Pay your attention to [Silverlight Unit Test Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut) too.

Comment: It seems it is not possible to associate SL unit tests to test cases in TFS. My SL unit tests were created using Silverlight Unit Test Framework. My guess is that this TFS association functionality is limited when it comes to SL (at he present moment).